# Accessing MSsql server from linux server using python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.6

I am trying access a stored procedure in MSSQL server using python pyodbc through an ajax call. Applicated is hosted in linux server. Whenever call to sp is made, procedure is executed and in database log "Password did not match that for the login provided" is printed.

The stored procedure which I am trying to execute through Ajax call retrieving dataset even though the error message in database log is printing.

Comment: Then the password and/or username is wrong. The error is telling you the problem. Check the username and password and correct the one that's wrong.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I want to know what is causing the db account lock. it is happening only when ajax call made through POST request.

Answer (score -1):

The stored procedure which i am trying to execute through Ajax call retrieving dataset even though the error message in database log is printing.